# Vitest config doesn't detect jsdom environment

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, jsdom, vitest

I'm in a Vite/React/TypeScript application and I'm configuring my first test with Vitest.

When I run my Button test (yarn vitest), I get this error:

```
packages/frontend/src/components/Generic/Button/Button.test.tsx > Button > should render the button
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

I understand that Vitest does not work with JSDom. I have tried several things:

- KO: Specifying in the vite.config.ts file to use JSDom
- OK: Adding a vitest.config.ts file specifying to use JSDom
- OK: Adding an annotation (@vitest-environment jsdom) at the top of the test file

I would prefere use the first option (use vite.config.ts) to share only one configuration. Is it possible ?

---

Note 1 : JSdom i already installed has "devDependencies".
Note 2 : to use vitest.config.ts i should update the script in package.json like that :
`"test": "vitest --config ./packages/frontend/vitest.config.ts"`

**Here are my files:**

```
// vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import viteTsConfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'
import tailwindcss from 'tailwindcss'

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    port: 4200,
    host: 'localhost',
  },

  rollupOption: {
    external: ['@internals/components/index']
  },

  define: {
    global: {},
  },

  plugins: [
    react(),
    tailwindcss(),
    viteTsConfigPaths({
      root: '../../',
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      // runtimeConfig is a special alias that is used to import the correct config file
      './runtimeConfig': './runtimeConfig.browser',

      // public alias
      '@publics': `${__dirname}/public`,

      // only internals (private) aliases are allowed here
      '@internals/components': `${__dirname}/src/components`,
      '@internals/features': `${__dirname}/src/features`,
      '@internals/hooks': `${__dirname}/src/hooks`,
      '@internals/models': `${__dirname}/src/models`,
      '@internals/utils': `${__dirname}/src/utils`,
      '@internals/types': `${__dirname}/src/types`,
      '@internals/styles': `${__dirname}/src/styles`,
      '@internals/assets': `${__dirname}/src/assets`,
      '@internals/store': `${__dirname}/src/store`,
      '@internals/config': `${__dirname}/src/config`,
      '@internals/services': `${__dirname}/src/services`,
    },
  },

  test: {
    globals: true,
    cache: {
      dir: '../../node_modules/.vitest',
    },
    environment: 'jsdom',
    include: ['*.tsx', '*.ts', '*.jsx', '*.js'],
  },
})
```

**I tried to add a like this vitest.config.ts :**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    include: ['*.ts', '*.tsx'], // FIXME
    environment: 'jsdom',
  },
})
```

Comment: Which command line do you use to run vitest? My colleague was using `npx vitest` and it didn't find jsdom because of that. Running in a script from the package.json worked (`npm run test`).